# How to align & distribute anchor points in a path in Flash CS6?

Tags: adobe-flash

I have drawn a path and would like to perfect its symmetry by aligning some of the anchor points vertically. The align panel seems to work well for objects, but I can't figure it out for individual path anchor points.  Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: The only vector tool I've ever seen that allowed this was CorelDraw. I think the closest you'll get is either dragging out guidelines or turning on and snapping to the grid.

Comment: I had used a feature like this in Inkscape. It was very useful for creating mirrored or symmetrical shapes. Are there any other techniques (aside from Amy's mentions) to accomplish something similar in Flash?

Comment: You can create half the shape and then overlap the ends. In Flash, this will make them join to form a single line.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Illustrator you can copy the path while in Flash, paste it into illustrator, select and then align the points using the alignment panel in illustrator, and then paste the updated path back into Flash.